# Horizontal label on link in graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force graph with label on links.
When the links were drawn with lines, the label was just on top of it, but since I have changed the lines with paths, the labels are too far from the path, especially when I drag away the nodes. 
Moreover when there are 2 links with the same source and target, the labels overlap :
[image: graph]

I would like something like that instead :
[image: graph2]

The label must be horizontal, it should not follow the path (thus, i cannot use a textPath)

I know my code in the tick for the label is wrong, but I dont have that much knowledge in maths...

```
lt.select(".link-text")
            .attr("dx", function (d) {
                var dx = (d.target.x + d.source.x) / 2;
                return dx;
            })
            .attr("dy", function (d) {
                var dy = (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2;
                return dy;
            });
```

Here the full code example with random positions :
http://jsfiddle.net/Lxc43v8d/31/